# How to lock nft in user's wallet?

Tags: nft

I'm now developing NFT backed loan site.
Before, I've sent NFT to escrow account but now I need to lock NFT in user's wallet.
Anyone know about locking nft in user's wallet, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

For NFTs, you can use look into using the [`FreezeDelegatedAccount`](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#freeze-the-token-account-as-a-delegate) and [`ThawDelegatedAccount`](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#thaw-the-token-account-as-a-delegate) instructions from the Metaplex Token Metadata program.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/issues/470#issuecomment-1132700105

> The important thing to notice is when creating the Master Edition
> Account, both the "Mint Authority" and the "Freeze Authority" are
> transferred to the Master Edition PDA!
>
> That means, no one can mint tokens or freeze accounts without going
> through the Token Metadata program.
>
> The Token Metadata program has no instruction that allows you to mint
> tokens so no one can ever mint additional tokens (which ensures the
> non-fungibility of the token).
>
> However, the Token Metadata program has one instruction that allows
> you to freeze the Token Account of the NFT. This is the
> FreezeDelegatedAccount instruction you are using.
>
> The requirements of that FreezeDelegatedAccount instruction are a bit
> unique. It requires you to be the Delegated Account of the Token
> Account to freeze.
>
> In order to be the Delegated Account of a Token Account, the owner of
> that Token Account must first use the Approve instruction from the SPL
> Token program. I am not 100% if it is possible for the Delegated
> address to be the same as the Owner's address but if not you could
> simply use another keypair you own.
>
> Now that you have a Delegated account on that Token Account, you can
> use the FreezeDelegatedAccount instruction of the Token Metadata
> program to freeze that Token Account.
>
> Note that you can also unfreeze it later using that same Delegated
> Account via the ThawDelegatedAccount instruction of the Token Metadata
> program.

Comment: Thank you for your posting answer.

Comment: As you know there might be many NFTs in user's wallet.
And their freeze authority is not mine. then how can I get freeze authority?
or how can I transfer freeze authority of NFT to me?

Comment: It doesn't work for pNFTs.
Do you have an idea for pNFT how to implement staking?
I think it can be implemented with lock and unlock of metaplex token metadata.
But I can't figure out how it work with onchain program.
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/ProgrammableNFTGuide.md